# RPi 4 as data storage accessible by "network not capable" device

Tags: gpio, pi-4

I would like to ask you if there is any way how to achieve the behaviour mentioned below with RPi 4. If so, can you describe how or provide some links with solutions of this issue?

Share a specific folder on SD card or connected USB storage device through ethernet in/output, convert its signal to USB and make it accessible by connected device, e.g. TV as a USB storage. The device should see it as connected USB external drive.
Or, use USB-C port OTG capability to do that. I think this might work, but I don't know how to separate power and data transfer. I doubt that TV can provide more than 1 A current through its USB port.

I think that the best solution is to just buy a TV which can connect to wifi and just use RPi 4 as NAS, but I'm curious if this can be achieved...I mean functional and safe solution without possibility that RPi or TV takes damage.

Comment: This sounds like more than one question but I'm a bit unclear on the specifics.  Can you solidify the questions?  It sounds like you (1) want to make media available to smart TV via USB (as if it were on a USB drive) but use Pi 4 instead; (2) instead of files being local to Pi 4, they would really be accessed via network (network filesystem - you didn't specific state this but you mentioned ethernet); (3) you want to use the USB-C port on the Pi (instead of USB 2 or 3) but also need to power the Pi and doubt TV can supply enough power.  Is that right?

Comment: More specifically: Connect Raspberry Pi to one TV through USB, but the TV should see it as connected USB drive with e.g photos, movies...because this TV is not capable to be connected to wifi or ethernet. Raspberry should also be NAS for other devices present in the house, which are capable of network connection. So, I want this older TV to access same data storage as other devices via directly connected Raspberry by USB, while other devices will use network to access same data storage (SSDs connected to the Raspberry)